# sms application intent not working in android 3.0 and above

Tags: android, sms, android-3.0-honeycomb

This is the piece of code I am using to call the SMS application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
            intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
            launchIntent(intent);
```

On devices with an os version below Android 3.0, the above code is working fine, the SMS page gets opened and the message to be sent and the numbers get prefilled correctly but in Android 3.0 and above devices this is not working anymore.

In Android 3.0 the SMS intent is called and the number gets filled and not the text where as in Android 4.0 the SMS intent is called and the text gets filled and not the number.

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works perfect

```
                String body = "This is the message i need to send";
                String num  = "smsto:999416231";
                String[] tokens = num.split(":");
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("address",tokens[1]);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body); 
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The code which i have mentioned in my question is use to pass the number as `Uri.parse(uri)` and its value is `"smsto:9941..."`

But in the new code i am splitting the text and number.

Comment: The problem with the code above is that it forces the user of the Android stock SMS messaging app because you're setting the "type" value of the intent.

Answer (score 1):

This code will works for all versions of android

```
String smsBody = Resources.getString("InvitationBody", getBaseContext()) + Local.User.FirstName;
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  i used as like above and now the message gets filled but not the sender number is missing...